# Angular JS. set ng-model correctly on repeatable select directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller, angularjs-ng-model

Just started learning AngularJS.
I wrote this controller and directive to repeat a select form item, because I need to do some server side work to populate its options.

Here is the directive in HTML:

```
<form-dropdown ng-init="getDropdown('category')" class="form-control"></form-dropdown>
```

Here is the controller, which does a .get to the script for each dropdown, and the directive:

```
$scope.getDropdown = function(query) {
        $http.get('assets/php/get_dropdown.php?op='+query)
        .success(function(data, status) {
                    $scope.select = data;
        });
};

myFormElementApp.directive('formDropdown', function() {
          return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: true,
                replace: true,
                template: '<select id="{{select.name}}" name="{{select.name}}" ng-options="template.key for template in select.items"></select>'
          };
    });
```

Here is the JSON I get back from my script to populate the select:

```
{
    "name":"category",
    "items":[
         {"key":"Choose Category","value":""},
         {"key":"Shirts","value":"shirts"},
         {"key":"Pants","value":"pants"},
         {"key":"Shoes","value":"shoes"},
         {"key":"Accessories","value":"accs"},
         {"key":"Cosmetics","value":"cosmetics"},   
         {"key":"Gift cards","value":"giftcards"}
    ]
}
```

I want the ng-model to be the "name" from JSON, but I get an error every time I put it into the directive template. I also want the select options' value to come from the JSON's "value" and the text from "key". I have the "key" where it should be, but the values are just the order of that item in the array (0, 1, 2, etc) and I have one of these as the first element of every select:

```
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
```

I have read elsewhere that the reason this happens because my model isn't set up correctly. How should I rewrite my controller or directive so that I can set ng-model correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should work

```
$scope.getDropdown = function(query) {
        $http.get('assets/php/get_dropdown.php?op='+query)
        .success(function(data, status) {
                    $scope.select = data;
$scope.dropValue = data.items[0];
        });
};


myFormElementApp.directive('formDropdown', function() {
          return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: true,
                replace: true,
                template: '<select id="{{select.name}}" name="{{select.name}}"
 ng-options="template.key for template in select.items track by template.key" ng-model="dropValue"></select>'
              };
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It does remove the weird first option, but I still need to get the values set correctly.

Comment: which property you want to set as a value ?

Comment: I want the options to have the JSON item.value. For example: `<option value="{{item.value}}">{{item.key}}</option>`

Should I have used ng-repeat for this instead? Probably gets rid of a lot of headache. And can I get the ng-model set as the name of the data instead of dropValue while preserving that function?

Comment: I switched the ng-options to `template.key for template in select.items track by template.value` and it worked! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: if you have not other issues, please also upvote my answer :) thanks in advance !

Comment: Will do once I hit 15 reputation!